# Remove everything except what is in brackets?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to remove all text except for `[` and `]` and what's between them. 
How would I go about doing that in Notepad++?

Example input:

```
[A B C] bla bla text here [D E F] bla bla text here [G H I] bla bla
bla here [J K L] M N O] bla bla text here [P Q R [S T U] even more bla
```

Desired output:

```
[A B C][D E F][G H I]
[J K L] M N O][P Q R [S T U]
```

The first line, where the brackets occur in matched `[`...`]` pairs,
is fairly easy to handle. 
The second one is tricky: I want to keep `[`...`]` pairs of brackets
even if they contain other brackets. 
(I’m having trouble finding a way to describe this precisely;
see the examples.)

I’ve developed a couple of solutions that get some cases right:

Answer 1:

```
Find what:    [^\]]+(\[|$)

Replace with: \1

Gives me:
[A B C][D E F][G H I]
[J K L] M N O][S T U]
```

Note that this one gets the `[J K L] M N O]` right
but discards the `[P Q R` .

---

Answer 2:

```
Find what:    [^\[]*(\[.*?\])[^\[]*

Replace with: $1

Gives me:
[A B C][D E F][G H I]
[J K L][P Q R [S T U]
```

This one, conversely, gets the `[P Q R [S T U]` right
but discards the  `M N O]`.

---

How can I get it to give me what I want?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t have Notepad++ (yeah, I know; I live in a cave),
but I do have `vi` (in Cygwin), and it seems to have similar capabilities. 
And this command

```
s/\(^\|]\)[^][]*\(\[\|$\)/\1\2/g
```

gave me your desired result for your input. 
I’ll explain, hopefully in enough detail to enable you
to translate it into Notepad++ese:

- The overall structure of `vi`’s **s**ubstitute command is:

  ```
  s (delimiter) (find what) (delimiter) (replace with) (delimiter) (options)
  ```

  where the conventional delimiter is `/`,
  and the `g` option stands for **g**lobal
  (i.e., do the substitution as many times as possible on each line). 
  So we have

  ```
  s/ (find what) / (replace with) /g
  ```
- My *find what* is `\(^\|]\)[^][]*\(\[\|$\)`. 
  In pieces (with spaces added to illuminate syntax):

  - `\( ^ \| ] \)`
    This is a capture group (`\(…\)`)
    that consists of the beginning of the line (`^`) or a `]`.
  - `[ ^ ][ ]`
    A set of characters. 
    `[^abc]` would match any character other than `a`, `b` or `c`. 
    This matches any character other than a `]` or a `[`. 
    (In Unix regular expressions, you include a `]` in a set of characters
    by putting it first, or immediately after an initial `^`. 
    Apparently in Notepad++ you do this by escaping it with `\`?)
  - `[ ^ ][ ] *`
    Zero or more of the above.
  - `\( \[ \| $ \)`
    Another capture group; this is sort-of the mirror image of the first one. 
    It is a `[` or the end of the line. 
    (We have to escape the `[` with a `\` to make it an ordinary character.)
- My *replace with* is `\1\2`,
  which is simply the two capture groups.

Putting it in English,
we remove maximal-length strings of characters other than `[` or `]`
that appear

- before the first `[` (i.e., between the beginning of the line and a `[`), or
- between a `]` and a `[`, or
- after the last `]` (i.e., between a `]` and the end of the line).

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|(?<=]))[^][]*?(?=\[|$)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # start non capture group
    ^       # beginning of line
  |         # OR
    (?<=])  # positive lookbehind, zero-length assertion that make sure we have a closing square bracket before
)           # end group
[^][]*?     # negative character class, any character that is not openning or closing square bracket, may appear 0 or more times, not greedy
(?=         # start positive lookahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we have after
    \[      # an openning square bracket
  |         # OR
    $       # end of line
)           # ed lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
[A B C][D E F][G H I]
[J K L] M N O][P Q R [S T U]
```